# What is the proof that $(a+b)^2 >a^2 + b^2$?

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

I would like to know if there is a theorem that proves that

> $$(a+b)^2>a^2+ b^2$$

where  $ab>0$

I am also wondering whether there is a name associated with this inequality.

Comment: Wrong if a=1 and b=-1.

Comment: good point, let me clarify i meant for positive numbers.

Comment: Read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for introduction to $\LaTeX$. Skip the introduction of [this](https://math-on-quora.surge.sh) (because the introduction is different and does not apply to this site, rest is same).

Comment: Expand the left hand side and cancel equal terms. What do you get?

Comment: thanks UmbQbify! since you visited this question, can I ask if you can perhaps help with the answer?

Comment: By definition, $A > B$  means $A - B$ is positive. What is $(a+b)^2 - (a^2+b^2)$?

Comment: @magnolia1, it will work if both numbers are negative. So it constraint should be $ab>0$ (i.e. of the same sign)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By distributing out, you get that

$${(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 = (a^2 + b^2) + 2ab}$$

Now - since ${a,b>0}$, then ${2ab>0}$. In other words, ${(a+b)^2 = (a^2 + b^2) + \text{a little bit}}$. So

$${(a+b)^2 = (a^2 + b^2) + 2ab > a^2 + b^2}$$

**Edit**: Indeed as @KeithBackman has remarked - this argument still works even if both ${a,b<0}$ - the point is, we just need ${2ab>0}$ for this argument to work. If they are both negative, ${2ab}$ is still ${>0}$, so the argument holds still :)

Comment: The condition $a,b>0$ is not required in the question; only $ab>0$, which is just as good for your argument.

Comment: @KeithBackman this is indeed true, I only put ${a,b>0}$ since that what the question said - I will edit my question to also add this comment, just for extra information. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2>a^2+b^2$$

Answer (score 3):

$$(a+b)^2-a^2-b^2=2ab>0$$

If $a$ and $b$ are of the same sign

Comment: The stated condition in the question $ab>0$ ensures $a$ and $b$ are of the same sign.